# How to enable -advanced-telemetry=true on AIR Adt to use on Scout

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adt, adobe-scout

I'm manually generating my swf, to after this to genrate an .apk

I want to enable the -advanced-telemetry to get the profile of each method call, as said on Scout.

I'm opening the Animator CC, and using DOM.exportSWF("mygenerated.swf", true);

to create the SWF

Comment: It is a compiler argument you use while compiling SWF, not APK itself.

Comment: ok thanks, I understood, but how to add this compiler argument?

Comment: I see, you use JSFL script. Well, good luck with that, for I have no idea what and how id does. I only know that **MXMLC** compiler supports that argument. Maybe, Flash IDE too, if you could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm compiling using PublishSettings.xml generated by Animator CC

So I found there were an option

```
<PublishFlashProperties enabled="true">
    <EnableTelemetry>1</EnableTelemetry>
    <TelemetryPassword/>
...
...
```

which enables the telemetry to be used on Adobe scout

so Now I can see the details of method calling on the Adobe Scout: